# CHM viewer with no continuous search?

Tags: software-recommendation, search

I am using [*CHMView*](http://trexinc.sourceforge.net/chmview.php) at the moment. 
The problem is that when I do a typing mistake in one word. 
I have to wait for long time. 
I would like to have no continuous search. 
Only searching when I hit enter.

**Is there any application for CHM where the search is not continuous?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [xCHM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xchm/) should do it for you. It doesn't use "live search". If you get an error (something about wxWidget) opening it, kill the app and restart it. The error should be gone afterwards.
2. [ichm](https://code.google.com/p/ichm/) - though using "live search" it's extremely fast. I never waited longer than 1 sec.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! xCHM is the better choice. iCHM is not possible because my documents are massive. Even your computer will be slow with these documents.